# Ruby parallel sorting

Tags: ruby, multithreading, sorting, concurrency, parallel-processing

I am trying to create a multithreaded version of a sorting algorithm. I do not understand why this algorithm always returns just `Array[1]` instead of the full array.

```
class Array
  def quick_sort
    return self if self.length <= 1
    pivot = self[0]
    if block_given?
      less, greater_equals = self[1..-1].partition { yield(x, pivot) }
    else
      less, greater_equals = self[1..-1].partition { |x| x < pivot }
    end
    l = []
    g = []
    Process.fork {l = less.quick_sort }
    Process.fork {g = greater_equals.quick_sort}
    Process.waitall
    return l + [pivot] + g
  end
end
```

Comment: What do you mean by `Array[1]`?

Comment: An array with a single element like `a = Array.new([1])`

Comment: Why don't you write `[1]`?

Comment: I am saying that this is what it is returning, not what I want, plus I am new to ruby, so I do not know all the code equivalences.

Comment: btw, you have a syntax error, one of the block does not include the right argument: `less, greater_equals = self[1..-1].partition { yield(x, pivot) }` should be `less, greater_equals = self[1..-1].partition { |x| yield(x, pivot) }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The local variables `l` and `g` are not passed beyond `Process.fork`. They are only valid within that block. For example,

```
Process.fork{a = 2}
Process.wait
a #=> NameError: undefined local variable or method `a' for main:Object
```

In your code, the `l` and `g` assignments done before `Process.fork` are still valid when you call `return l + [pivot] + g`.

By the way, if you had intended `l` and `g` to be passed from `Process.fork`, then your initialization of these variables prior to `Process.fork` is meaningless.

Comment: But from what I read, if I do `l = Process.fork {less.quick_sort}`, L is now the pid of the fork and not the return of the process.

Answer (score 1):

From you examples it looks like you are trying to use Process where you actually want to use a [thread](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Thread.html).

**Process:** no shared resources with itś caller (Parent)

**Thread:** shares memory with its Parent

Your example would work if you replaced the `Process.fork` with `Threads`:

```
l = []
g = []
left_thread = Thread.new {l = less.quick_sort }
right_thread = Thread.new {g = greater_equals.quick_sort}
left_thread.join
right_thread.join
return l. + [pivot] + g
```